# Google Music with .NET - Fetch a Track

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-music

I am building a mini music player in .net for google music. I can get the playlist(s) from [here](https://www.googleapis.com/sj/v1/playlists). And I can see the playlist id, but how can I get the individual tracks from the playlist?

```
{
 "kind": "sj#playlistList",
 "data": {
 "items": [
 {
    "kind": "sj#playlist",
    "id": "935bfa54-36e4-452c-aa20-56c2835cb889",
    "creationTimestamp": "1387143940668642",
    "lastModifiedTimestamp": "1387143940668642",
    "recentTimestamp": "1387143940666000",
    "deleted": false,
    "name": "Playlist 1",
    "type": "USER_GENERATED",
    "shareToken": "AMaBXykhyJQbceb6PUidlvLZn-pFLIppvAeR8qrKqBmPk8c4WCLL551RKi6Q7AQWAsINM1PkM-LZq8rkUhVyavAxS8xhyqtEsA==",
    "ownerName": "Some Owner",
    "ownerProfilePhotoUrl": "http://someurl",
    "accessControlled": false
  }
}
```